# Referrer is logged, but HttpReferrer is null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on your basic anti-leech (black list variety).  I'm getting these referrers in the logs, but when I try to access the `Request.UrlReferrer`, it's `null`. So is `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")`

Here's an example of the referrer. These are showing up in the IIS log files, but as the request comes in, I can't access it in code behind to check it against my black list.

```
http://www.pinsdaddy.com/cambria-california-wedding-photography-18-mirrors-edge_cJ8jn4pAJmKSlbTCSdOcIvct6EKJC1hNE9RvlPVWmmc3iL7RWbE8NWPK2e3AlHufGJ5Y4wEz0KwkTr5tdCFtuA/HU*r3vNj3fj*lmybrtHKWHIaJbhl%7CrPNYEBp5h1LLrgiOrQqUd1yFlcQ4zk2Fg92M72f*uRfYUoZ5yXmlQZOG7*Zo6iLIcxD1tBIqMGCECNyCYSstZQN4HOcXTJocIDYNEftok4Anz4aQVpSK0CYVtVI7pYG51JUH3TWgg0KEUQRZd5ZF8UI4qQ5tseiERUk7gsHebxA3eF1LCFjrZ4PHw/
```

Since I'm logging this nasty thing, I can't figure out why it's not available in my HTTP module.  Every other site that hotlinks to the images are fine - just not this particularly nasty one.

I've tried various approaches. `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri`, `Request.UrlReferrer.Host`, etc.

```
string referrer = "Empty Referrer";
HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
if (context.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    referrer = context.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

I'm starting to wonder if the character combinations in the referrer value are blowing up somewhere in .NET. IIS gets it fine, so I *ought* to be able to access it in code.

Note - these are http to http requests. No SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you actually don't need to implement your own codes to handle this issue

IIS rewrite module can do basic stuff which can solve you problem

if i were correct, you want to block certain request with certain referral or you may just want to block all

the example is for blocking only http://*.pinsdaddy.com and http://*.somesite.com

and also you can add as many as you want, and with regex

```
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="http://*.pinsdaddy.com" />
            <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="http://*.somesite.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm actually trying that right now.  Your approach is a little simpler than others I've seen, using rewriteMaps. I'll give that a try- thank you!

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, even though it didn't help me deal with malformed URI's in a referrer, this does work. Thanks again!

Comment: if you want to deal with malformed uri, you can try regex on pattern. then you will need to change the patternSyntax="ECMAScript", and modify both <match> and <condition> patterns